# I am trying to download excel (.xlsx) file by using following code

Tags: java, spring-boot

File getting downloaded successfully but I cannot open file, it seems to be corrupted.Not sure what I am missing.

```
public StreamingResponseBody getStreamingFile() throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"discrepancyReport.xls\"");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(rootPath + ".xlsx"));

        return outputStream -> {
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        };
```

Comment: concrete error message when trying to open?

Comment: I am working on Mac.Following is the message: There is no application set to open the document “application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet_downloadReport_blob_http___localhost_8080_a3a7d503-6619-4e92-a532-9807ccd9d00f”.

Comment: if that refers to the excel file itself, I'd assume, that you haven't installed excel

Comment: Yes.I tried to open with it.I see following message : Excel could not open application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml (2).sheet_downloadReport_blob_http___localhost_8080_c255a289-e5d0-45ae-ad4d-a00cdd59cee3.xlsx because some content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?

Comment: can you downlaod the file via browser and try to open again? currently, there are a few (byte) errors in the file. this happens if something (maybe bytes) missing

Comment: I downloaded it through browser it self.

Comment: The filename in the Content-disposition is wrong: "discrepancyReport.xls" should be "discrepancyReport.xlsx"

Comment: I have changed it to .xlsx.But no luck.Same issue.

Comment: `.xls` and `.xlsx` only tell you which office version it was created with. `xls` is 2003 and before and `xlsx` is after 2003. if you downloaded the file through a browser and the error pops up, then there is a error in the file which you can't fix while downloading

Comment: So is there any better to way to download it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be with swagger.When I tried hitting end-point directly, It is working as expected.